# Why does 64 bit apache show httpd as 32 bit?

Tags: windows, apache-2.4

I am trying to install Apache 64 bit on Windows Server 2012.  I am using the download link - https://www.apachelounge.com/download/

Whenever I unzip the Win64 variations I take a look at the httpd executable and it says that it is W32 with a Architecture as 32-bit.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

How are you looking at it? Sysinternals shows 64 bit.

```
PS C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\httpd-2.4.26-Win64-VC15\Apache24\bin> sigcheck.exe .\httpd.exe

Sigcheck v2.54 - File version and signature viewer
Copyright (C) 2004-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\httpd-2.4.26-Win64-VC15\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe:
        Verified:       Unsigned
        Link date:      05:05 2017-06-14
        Publisher:      n/a
        Company:        Apache Software Foundation
        Description:    Apache HTTP Server
        Product:        Apache HTTP Server
        Prod version:   2.4.26
        File version:   2.4.26
        MachineType:    64-bit
```